# The 'code-reuse' and 'reusability' tags should probably be merged

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

I can't find a sensible difference between the [code-reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse) and the [reusability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reusability) tags.

Other similar tags were already merged into these two in [please-tag-synonym-all-of-the-code-reuse-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157590/please-tag-synonym-all-of-the-code-reuse-tags), but I can't see a reason to leave these two separate.
I think it was done this way at that time because the moderator was unsure and for the time being he just put the tags containing "code" in one tag and the rest in another.

By now though it seems pretty clear that there should be a single tag.

I don't have enough reputation to use the tag synonym feature myself, and even if I had I'm not 100% sure yet (opinions welcome).

---

#### Which tag should be merged into which?

Personally I think [code-reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse) is a clearer name, less likely to be misused.