# Merge synonyms of [readability] and [maintainability]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

It looks like these two tag have synonyms. Could each set be reduced by merging?

[readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability): merge in [code-readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-readability)

[maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintainability): merge in [code-maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-maintainability) and [maintaining-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maintaining-code)

(Note: [A similar request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345787/the-code-reuse-and-reusability-tags-should-probably-be-merged) seems to have merged [reusability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reusability) and [code-reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse) into [reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reuse).)